# Fires presentedViewController several times

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, modalviewcontroller, viewcontroller, viewdidappear

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
if (!self.hasPresentedModalMenuView) {

    NSLog(@"Firing");
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"highScoresStory" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"highScores"];
[vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];


} }
```

This Keeps Repeating over and over again. I have taken out the code below "Firing", and if I do that, it only fires once. Why does this keep firing? Thank You for any help.

Comment: Are you trying to present the same view controller over and over again? What class is this code in?

Comment: There's not nearly enough here to answer this question.  Where does this code exist?  What are you actually trying to do? And if you're using storyboards, why aren't you using segues?

Comment: So, I have a scene, let's call it "MyScene". In my scene, I use this:  MyScene *viewHigh = [[MyScene alloc] init];
                 UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
                [vc presentViewController: viewHigh animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: to go to another view controller. When that view controller loads, I set the story board